# Repair of HP Photosmart 3310

Tags: printer, scanner, all-in-one, legacy

Does any service actually *repair* printers?

I have two(2) [HP Photosmart 3310](https://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-Photosmart-3310-Multifunction-Printer/4331530) All-in-one printers, each with a different bad component (one the circuit board, and the other a drive gear).  I'd really love to be able to get a good usable one between the two.

I know printers (especially inkjets) are really just designed to be disposable.  But the 3310 has truly been the best printer I've ever used, between it's 6 cartrigdes (light cyan and light magenta in addition to CYMK) and it's ability to take any paper - be it lightweight, cardstock, photopaper, etc.

I'm sure I saw ink cartridges for it sold at Staples the last time I was there, so ink should be no problem - and that also implies I'm not the only one that really liked the printer.

I've searched for repair services, but all I've found are sites selling HP's current new printers.  I started trying to repair it myself, but found it too involved to do with the limited free time I have, unfortunately.

So, does anyone know of a repair service?  Or, anyone know the magic keyword incantation to have Google find one for me?

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Aside from that, they're not worth anyone's time to repair. A tech would charge the same to open one up for preliminary tests as you could buy another for. It might be a fun DIY project, but not one you could pay someone else to do, economically.

Comment: This is a printer from 2005. I really do not see any reason you want to repair them.